# How does kfam interact with central-dashboard in Kubeflow and does it involve KUBEFLOW_USERID header?

Tags: kubeflow

This is about kubeflow. I am unclear about the role of kfam. it appears the central-dashboard needs to know about kfam svc. Hence it (central-dashboard) takes kfam url from configmap (PROFILES_KFAM_SERVICE_HOST). It calls kfam APIs to do what? What interaction do central-dashboard <--> kfam do? Does KUBEFLOW_USERID play a role in it?

Answer (score 0):

KFAM is a GO library in kubeflow that helps in implementing Kubernetes RBAC in kubeflow through profile.
In your case, KFAM tells Central Dashboard what all resources (notebooks, notebook servers, pipelines) user has access to. This happens everytime you switch your profile or refresh your page for that user. Hope this answers your question.